# Can i change the action name in Touch ID pop-up from "Enter password" to "Enter passcode"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-id

[image]

In our application we need "Enter Passcode", but by default TouchID pop-up shows "Enter password" when user touchID authentication failed.This may confuse users because the same user has another password for different purpose.

Can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change it with:

```
 let authenticationContext = LAContext()
 authenticationContext.localizedFallbackTitle = "Enter passcode"
```